# Is it possible to find minimum values removing duplicates?

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, minimum, euclidean-distance

I am measuring the Euclidean distances between two groups. I need to assign to each member of group A the closest member of group B in terms of Euclidean distance. Up to this point, I believe my procedure is correct. However, I want to avoid duplicates and hence pick the second smallest distance.
Do you know how to solve my issue? Thank you

This is group A and its values

```
structure(c(-0.437386713797664, -0.322509898825902, -0.446772199812171, 
-0.306377907447282, -1.16112799940137, -1.21883627368898, 0.781449863630165, 
0.809057731590798, 0.835317797489122, 1.06338635042331, 1.14766147279867, 
1.19990154848243, 0.541647078855247, 0.331402541373546, 0.769635896131398, 
0.917183368867628, 1.03537152083825, 1.07248200987546, -0.84281537834569, 
-0.930210645532507, -0.95363670318317, -1.44749695166376, -1.00070628841024, 
-0.995990975222219, -0.899180629655196, -1.10461822903083, -0.870840897760359, 
-1.75438726810843, -0.865778818512406, -0.97141864352977, -0.0488353188258754, 
0.0151038610915593, -0.124663639383948, -0.119947013154793, -0.241497348414719, 
-0.238657452863602, -5.76575157521609, -4.79779097127126, -5.65868946937647, 
-4.48335470544075, -5.64312030815928, -5.48298506172842), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(
    c("AEURLNE", "AEURLWT", "MGPESEC", "MPSECIA", "ABETEIE", 
    "ABNETI2"), NULL))
```

This is group B and its values

```
structure(c(-1.03112543288906, -0.732243802845452, -1.35470517335279, 
            -1.36053108150905, -1.34211017475077, -0.564986981205769, 1.02274636573912, 
            1.21449561985436, 1.27010234483145, 1.28100364050786, 1.03879273199055, 
            0.73369904880266, 1.03528602357854, 0.889285434588302, 1.23974455852262, 
            1.24675131474449, 1.08410292343277, 0.701889673393536, -0.757916313490645, 
            -1.17553443265399, -1.12241876073598, -1.13227804066401, -0.654107359657692, 
            -0.766577908429598, -0.865546543693128, -0.566753478389543, -1.43552219875369, 
            -1.42105971033212, -0.685335620288824, -0.813149610659778, -0.115942551557779, 
            -0.102054203575614, -0.0399077512941925, -0.0326201836357187, 
            -0.0924513819642168, -0.0657275077209774, -6.28621491621599, 
            -6.00048564535606, -5.23999569980309, -5.25725813719781, -6.89372539548915, 
            -5.67715042107208), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(c("CIFEEIC", 
                                                               "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), NULL))
```

Hence, I run the following

```
 library(pdist)#install.packages("pdist")
library(fields)
```

I compute the Euclidean distance between A and B

```
EuclideanD = as.data.frame(rdist(betasESG,betasCONV))
colnames(EuclideanD) = rownames(B)
rownames(EuclideanD) = rownames(A)
```

Then I find the closest but I have duplicates:

```
test1 = colnames(EuclideanD)[apply(EuclideanD,1,which.min)]
```

Comment: Could you share your code so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read through [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then edit your question according to the guidelines on SO. :-)